# Is it possible to extract information from older website version using python?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I would like to extract old version of website, with their current url's. I don't know if that's possible. At the end I would like to compare their old version with the new ones. Many thanks!

Comment: you could probably use https://web.archive.org/web/ .

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it could indeed help a lot, I will dig deeper into it